# How to upload image file to remote server folder using php script

Tags: php

Sir ..

Please help me to find code to upload image file from one computer to remote server folder using php script.

Comment: Do some searching on google and follow some tutorials...

Comment: Possible Solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702910/how-to-upload-an-image-onto-localhost-server-whilst-path-is-stored-in-mysql-data

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure that PHP is configured to allow file uploads.

In your "php.ini" file, search for the file_uploads directive, and set it to On:

```
file_uploads = On
```

Next, create an HTML form that allow users to choose the image file they want to upload:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and create "upload.php" file looks like this:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here example: u need to create input form with file. Then chek if isset, some checks for extension and size, and move it.

```
private function _uploadAvatar() {
        if (isset($_POST["uploadImage"])) {
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $params = explode('/', PARAMS);
            $userId = end($params);
            $temp = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"]; // Temporary name of image
            $name = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]; // Name of image
            $size = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"]; // Size
            $ext = finfo_file($finfo, $temp);
            $uploadMaxSize = $this->convertMegabytestoBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
            $postMaxSize = $this->convertMegabytestoBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
            $extensions = array("image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/gif");

            if ($size > $uploadMaxSize || $size > $postMaxSize) {
                echo 'File is too big';
            }
            if (!in_array($ext, $extensions)) {
                echo 'File is not valid image';
            }
            if (empty($_SESSION['errors'])) {
                move_uploaded_file($temp, __SITE_PATH . "/pictures/" . $name);
                $path = URL . '/pictures/' . $name;
                $user = new user($this->registry);
                $user->uploadAvatar($userId, $path);
                echo 'Image was successful upload';
                header("Refresh:2");
            }
        }
    }
```